# Pyqt step size for lists with a large gap between average and maximum value

Tags: python, list, pyqt, pyqt5

I am building a tool in pyqt that has a slider which sorts areas of geomtries.
In some cases there can be data with extremely large gap between average or mininum area value and the maximum.

Let it be like:
`areas = [0.5, 1.0, 1.3, 1.7, 2.6, 3.0, 3.5, 3.9, 4.0, 4.1, 1023.8, 3245.4, 3734.3]`

When I set min and max values for slider, about 95 % of slider bar are values from 5 to 3245.4. I am looking for some solution to make a some kind of dynamic step size for slider in order to see every possible value from areas list. I.e some kind of this

`0________________________________5.0____________________________________3734.3
 ^                                 ^                                      ^`

Answer (score 2):

If you have a list of values and don't want something like a *log* slider, you can subclass `QSlider` and handle the values based on the indexes in the list.

A quick example:

```
class Slider(QSlider):
    doubleValueChanged = pyqtSignal(float)
    def __init__(self, values, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.values = values
        self.setOrientation(Qt.Horizontal)
        self.setRange(0, len(self.values) - 1)
        self.setTickInterval(1)
        self.valueChanged.connect(lambda index: self.doubleValueChanged.emit(self.values[index]))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    slider = Slider([0.5, 1.0, 1.3, 1.7, 2.6, 3.0, 3.5, 3.9, 4.0, 4.1, 1023.8, 3245.4, 3734.3])
    slider.doubleValueChanged.connect( lambda value: print("New value", value))
    slider.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I created a new signal because `QSlider` works only with integers.

If you want to add the labels, you can redefine `QSlider.paintEvent`